# Adding document to collection depending on existance of document from different collection

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

On Firestore I am trying to add a document to one collection based on the existance of another document from a different collection. For example, if a certain session exists in my session collection, then an attendance record can be added to the attendance collection. Is this possible to achieve on Cloud Firestore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this on user side by calling `exists()` method on a `DocumentSnapshot` object to check if a particular document exists or not in your `session` collection like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference docRef = rootRef.collection("session").document(docId);
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                //Add attendance record to the attendance collection
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

To be 100% procent sure you can also use security rules as also @Gerardo mentioned in his answer, where you can use again `exists()` method to see if a certain session exists or not in your session collection and reject the action accordingly.

Comment: Both work and Alex I have used your solution, works perfect but I just need to add to this if I can. Could you please check my updated question as I want to improve upon the reliability of this.

Comment: But don't edit the question with other demands. This is basically another question. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you. PS. I just rolled back to the original one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function 'exists' within your security rules to validate the a specific document exists on a different collection. Check this document for reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents